# Фиксированный заголовок таблицы Footable (плагин Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, footable

форумчане, пользуюсь для своего сайта таблицей footable. Столкнулся с такой проблемой что не могу реализовать фиксированный заголовок при вертикальной прокрутке таблицы, создал для этого отдельный блочный элемент со свойством sticky, может я как-то не так использую или ещё что, подскажите, пожалуйста. Все скрипты и таблицы стилей использую стандартные для плагина

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 2em;
  background: lightpink;
}

.raz {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  /* This is a (hacky) way to make the .grid element size to fit its content */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="raz">
  <table class="table" id="maintable">

    <thead>

      <tr class="sticky">
        <th data-breakpoints="xs">ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs">Job Title</th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs sm">Started On</th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md" data-title="DOB">Date of Birth</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr data-expanded="true">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Dennise</td>
        <td>Fuhrman</td>
        <td>High School History Teacher</td>
        <td>November 8th 2011</td>
        <td>July 25th 1960</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Elodia</td>
        <td>Weisz</td>
        <td>Wallpaperer Helper</td>
        <td>October 15th 2010</td>
        <td>March 30th 1982</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Raeann</td>
        <td>Haner</td>
        <td>Internal Medicine Nurse Practitioner</td>
        <td>November 28th 2013</td>
        <td>February 26th 1966</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Junie</td>
        <td>Landa</td>
        <td>Offbearer</td>
        <td>October 31st 2010</td>
        <td>March 29th 1966</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Solomon</td>
        <td>Bittinger</td>
        <td>Roller Skater</td>
        <td>December 29th 2011</td>
        <td>September 22nd 1964</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Lewis</td>
        <td>Clown</td>
        <td>November 12th 2012</td>
        <td>August 4th 1991</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Usha</td>
        <td>Leak</td>
        <td>Ships Electronic Warfare Officer</td>
        <td>August 14th 2012</td>
        <td>November 20th 1979</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Lorriane</td>
        <td>Cooke</td>
        <td>Technical Services Librarian</td>
        <td>September 21st 2010</td>
        <td>April 7th 1969</td>
      </tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Dennise</td>
      <td>Fuhrman</td>
      <td>High School History Teacher</td>
      <td>November 8th 2011</td>
      <td>July 25th 1960</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Elodia</td>
        <td>Weisz</td>
        <td>Wallpaperer Helper</td>
        <td>October 15th 2010</td>
        <td>March 30th 1982</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>Raeann</td>
        <td>Haner</td>
        <td>Internal Medicine Nurse Practitioner</td>
        <td>November 28th 2013</td>
        <td>February 26th 1966</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>]

<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/footable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.table').footable();

  });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо отделить контент таблицы от заголовка

```
table tbody, table thead
{
    display: block;
}
```

только после этого можно использовать sticky, overflow: auto и т. п.

но теперь заголовок отвязан от таблицы и не разделяет с ней общую ширину. 
ширину придется задать вручную

```
th
{
    width: 72px;
}
td
{
    width: 72px;
}
```

Comment: блок sticky всё равно не захватывает заголовок таблицы, а остается выше как при отображении, так и в коде страницы браузера не захватывая thead, хоть и в саблайме thead внутри этого блока